# Check Random file in directory

Tags: vb.net

i have the following code that save text from textbox to directory the problem i want when file saved textbox clear all text but the code clear textbox and when i open a file in directory is empty  how to check if file saved and clear(but file saved random)

```
If Not (System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName.ToString + "\AppData\SystemInfo\TextLogs")) Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName.ToString + "\AppData\SystemInfo\TextLogs")
    End If
    If (System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName.ToString + "\AppData\SystemInfo\TextLogs")) Then

        Dim count As Integer = -1
        Dim files As String = TextBox1.Text

        Dim writerz As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName.ToString + "\AppData\SystemInfo\TextLogs\" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".txt")




        writerz.WriteLine(files)


textbox1.clear()


    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close and dispose a StreamWriter because its internal buffer of data is not written to disk every time you call WriteLine

```
Dim folder = System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\Users", Environment.UserName,"AppData\SystemInfo\TextLogs"
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folder)

Dim file = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder,DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".txt")
Using writerz As New IO.StreamWriter(file)
    writerz.WriteLine(files)
End Using
```

Here the `Using` statement ensures that the file is properly closed and disposed when the code reaches the `End Using` statement

Side notes:

1. You can use [File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.8)/[WriteAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8) to simplify your code
2. [System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_CreateDirectory_System_String_) checks internally if the directory already
   exists so you don't need all that code. Just
   Directory.CreateDirectory even if the directory exists.